# What was the font of the first printed edition of Rash"i's commentary?

Tags: rashi, books-generally

In what font was the first printed edition of Rash"i's commentary on the Torah printed? Was it some "standard" Hebrew block print or something more like [the type face so eponymously associated with the man today](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi_script)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia entry on Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi#Commentary_on_the_Tanakh),

> The first dated Hebrew printed book was Rashi's commentary on the Chumash, printed by Abraham ben Garton in Reggio di Calabria, Italy, 18 February 1475. (This version did not include the text of the Chumash itself.)

Some good images of that sefer can be found [here](http://jewishcalabria.blogspot.com/2008/03/and-we-have-revealed-to-you.html). And yes, they are in "Rashi script"!

Comment: Is that why it's called Rashi script, or did Rashi's writing look anything like that?

Comment: see here: http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2009/04/rashi-script.html

Answer (score 8):

There's an undated edition of Rashi (also without the Chumash text) that is generally assumed to be from about 1470 - a few years earlier than Garton's edition referenced in Dave's response. A facsimile is at [Hebrewbooks](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/44341) - and it's in square (not "Rashi") type.